# Json_encode no regresa nada de arreglo con tildes en PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

```
 function fnObtenerPagosRopaReferencia()
    {
      
        $numprov = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num_prov", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        $numReferencia = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num_referencia", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        $treemonth=mktime(0,0,0,date("m")-3,date("d"),date("Y"));
        $fecha= strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$treemonth);
        try{

            $model = new PagosRopaModel();
            $nr = $model -> fnobtenerPagosRopaReferencia($numprov,$fecha,$numReferencia);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "A ocurrido un problema al obtener la informacion";
            exit;
        }
        
        echo json_encode($nr);
    }
```

El problema es al momento de llamar `json_encode`, si el contenido de una posición del arreglo contiene una tilde, el `json_encode` no retorna nada, al momento de hacer la conexión se utiliza lo siguiente (la variable *nr* es un arreglo):

```
    public function __construct($ConnecionInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_ConnectionInfo = $ConnecionInfo;

            $this->_ConnectionInfo->Server() . ";Database=" . $this->_ConnectionInfo->DataBase(),
             $this->_Connection = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};server=" . $this->_ConnectionInfo->Server() . ";Database=" . $this->_ConnectionInfo->DataBase(),
                                          $this->_ConnectionInfo->User(), 
                                          $this->_ConnectionInfo->Password());
            $this->_Connection->setAttribute(constant('PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY'), true);
            $this->_Connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(Exception $Ex)
        {
            if($this->_Connection==null)
            {
                #throw new Exception("No fue posible etablecer la conexión al servidor " . $this->_ConnectionInfo->Server() . ".");
                throw new Exception($Ex->getMessage(), $Ex->getCode(), $Ex->getPrevious());
            }
            else
            {
                // //
            }
        }
    }
```

Buscando en Google, encontré que utilizando el driver de odbc no se puede agregar un segundo parámetro del encoding utf-8 como con SQL, por lo que por más que busco no encuentro solución alguna.
No tengo acceso para modificar algo de la configuración de SQL ni del archivo php.ini ya que es un servidor de producción, ¿hay algo que pueda realizar?

Comment: Probaste [*utf8_encode*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)?

Comment: Funciona, pero es un arreglo con miles de registros, buscaba alguna opción en la que no necesite recorrer el arreglo

Comment: ¿Qué codificación usa la Base de Datos?

Comment: Qué versión de PHP?

Comment: ¿Intentaste con `$this->_Connection->setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);`?

Answer (score 0):

**Si estás usando PHP 7.2 o superior**, puedes usar [el segundo parámetro de json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) para refinar su comportamiento. Este parámetro se pasa a través de constantes. Por ejemplo

```
 json_encode($nr, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE)
```

o bien:

```
 json_encode($nr, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE)
```

Si estás usando php 7.3 puedes además hacer que tire una excepción para saber qué caracteres están causando el problema:

```
 json_encode($nr, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE | JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)
```

Aprovecha que ya tienes un bloque try/catch:

```
try{

     $model = new PagosRopaModel();
     $nr = $model -> fnobtenerPagosRopaReferencia($numprov,$fecha,$numReferencia);

     echo json_encode($nr, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE | JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

 }catch(Exception $e){
     echo "Ha ocurrido un problema al obtener la informacion";
     exit;
 }
```

(separé las flags con un pipe |, son operaciones bitwise)

**Si estás con versiones anteriores**: por favor actualiza. Pero por mientras, puedes usar [json_last_error_msg](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-last-error-msg.php). Algo como

```
if(!$texto = json_encode($nr)) {
   throw new Exception(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

quedaría:

```
try{

     $model = new PagosRopaModel();
     $nr = $model -> fnobtenerPagosRopaReferencia($numprov,$fecha,$numReferencia);

     if(!$texto = json_encode($nr)) {
         throw new Exception(json_last_error_msg());
     }

     echo  $texto;

 }catch(Exception $e){
     echo "Ha ocurrido un problema al obtener la informacion";
     exit;
 }
```